# Get top values from two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
id  |  peru  | usa
 1      20      10
 2       5      100
 3       1       5
```

How can I get the top values from `peru` and `usa` as well as the spefic ids. So that I get as result:

```
usa_id: 2 | usa: 100 |  peru_id: 1 | peru: 20
```

Is this possible In **one** query? Or do I have to do two `ORDER BY` querys?

Im using postgresql

Comment: it is possible with one query

Comment: @Lashane  Could you please write an answer with the query? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, but we're not free code writing community

Comment: @Lashane! It would be enough if you could provide me an link!! I mean this table was only as example! Thanks!

Comment: link to what? ansi sql standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some subqueries and a cross join:

```
select
    u.id usa_id,
    u.usa,
    p.id peru_id,
    p.peru
from
    (select id, usa from mytable where usa=(select max(usa) from mytable) order by id limit 1) u
    cross join (select id, peru from mytable where peru=(select max(peru) from mytable) order by id limit 1) p
;
```

In the case that there are multiple rows with the same max value (for usa or peru, independently), this solution will select the one with the lowest id (I've assumed that id is unique).

Comment: Since this query basically consists of those two queries you're referring to, plus joins them and aliases a couple of their columns, I would expect this query to take marginally more time than running the two queries separately, but the difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  t1.id as peru_id, t1.peru
  , t2.id as usa_id, t2.usa
FROM tab1 t1, tab1 t2 
ORDER BY t1.peru desc, t2.usa desc
limit 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c12f/6

As basicly what this does is a simple carthesian product - I guess that performance WILL be poor for large datasets.

on the fiddle it took [196ms for a 1k rows table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cdbf9/2). On 10k rows table - sqlFiddle hung up.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using MAX aggregate function in conjunction with ARRAY type. Check this out:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _test(
id integer primary key,
peru integer not null,
usa integer not null
);

INSERT INTO _test(id, peru, usa)
VALUES
(1,20,10),
(2,5,100),
(3,1,5);

SELECT MAX(ARRAY[peru, id]) AS max_peru, MAX(array[usa, id]) AS max_usa FROM _test;

SELECT x.max_peru[1] AS peru, x.max_peru[2] AS peru_id, x.max_usa[1]
AS usa, x.max_usa[2] AS usa_id FROM (
   SELECT MAX(array[peru, id]) AS max_peru, 
   MAX(array[usa, id]) AS max_usa FROM _test ) as x;
```